# No reputation gain with information "You reached reputation cap for this post"

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Some one has upvoted on my answer, I can see the vote count, but when I hover my profile link, I see zero reputation with tooltip "You reached reputation cap for this post"

[image]

Searched on the meta stackoverflow, but didn't get any exact answer.
So please let me know

- What does this imply
- Why it is there?
- Why it changes daily?

Comment: oh - and well done BTW :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text is somewhat misleading. You actually reached the reputation cap for the day.

You can earn up to 200 rep from upvotes in a day. Rep from accepted answers and bounties do not count towards the cap.

Comment: In that case why it changes daily? Yesterday it was 260? Day before that it was around 275? For some user like [Jon Skeet on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), daily reputation eared is over 500? Any explanation on this

Comment: @Amar: please read up on [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) The reputation cap only limits upvotes, edits, and other things. Reputation gained from bounties and accepted answers does not count towards the limit.

Comment: @amar as I said, accepts don't count.  If you hit the limit at 260, that means you had (at least) 20 upvotes and 4 answers accepted.

Comment: @Kevin: By the way, suggested edits are capped by the daily reputation limit as well.

Comment: @Amar - To get 500 points you only need to reach the 200 point rep  cap, *plus* get 20 accepted answers a day. No problem! :-)

Comment: @bopersson Jon skeet could do that.  Us mere mortals have to use bounties to get that high.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, today I 10 x 15 answer were accepted and 20 x 10 upvotes, counted to 350.

Comment: @BoPersson, Jon Skeet has reached 515 :)

Comment: @AmarPalsapure I believe his highest is actually 770, going by the reputation graph.