# “You reached the reputation cap for this post”, but it's not my post and the cap is far away

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gaining/losing 0 reputation on questions I've not asked or answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/gaining-losing-0-reputation-on-questions-ive-not-asked-or-answered)

I downvoted a question today, but only that, I didn't answer it.

Now this question is in my activity overview, with rep 0 and a tooltip, **“You reached the reputation cap for this post”**.

I am not able to get rep for this post nor did it cost me any. This post should not be in my activity overview.

**I only got four upvotes today, far away from the rep cap, so what happened here?**

There is a similar question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121113/no-reputation-gain-with-information-you-reached-reputation-cap-for-this-post), but that guy really reached the rep cap, I didn't.

[image]